# Accessing WCF service with Integrated Windows Authentication from Windows Service using local SYSTEM account

Tags: wcf, windows-services, windows-authentication, wcf-security, wcf-client

We have WCF service using Integrated windows authentication deployed on a dedicated server.
There will be Windows Service on Client machines[windows service uses Local System Account].We get an error when the WCFServiceClient in Windows service accesses the WCF service.[If windows service is on server machine it works fine]

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

We cannot allow anonymous access or can not remove windows authentication from WCF service. Is there a way to get around this problem.

The config on client side is

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicServiceHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The server config is

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        /binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: any solution mister Deepak N ?? question dated in Feb 11...

Comment: No.The service should be run under Network service OR Domain account of the user. However Network service approach did not work in windows server 2003 machines...